# What is idiomatic way to serialize DOM document with S9API serializer

Tags: java, saxon, s9api

Using Saxon S9API, what is the idiomatic way to serialize a DOM document to output stream? Something like

```
Serializer result = processor.newSerializer(out);
XdmNode source = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new DOMSource(doc));
result.serializeNode(source);
```

works but is there more correct way in S9API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do `DocumentBuilder.build()` because that will copy the whole DOM to a tree using the default tree model (normally a TinyTree). Instead you can use `DocumentBuilder.wrap()` (supplying the DOM Document node) which simply creates an XdmNode as a wrapper around the DOM node.

So:

```
Serializer result = processor.newSerializer(out);
XdmNode source = processor.newDocumentBuilder().wrap(doc);
result.serializeNode(source);
```